# JWT-Auth for Laravel Dingo API package not able to login

Tags: php, api, authentication, laravel-4, jwt

I have been trying to implement the `JWT-Aut` in Laravel's [Dingo API](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Authentication) package, but I am stuck at users Login part, I have checked the official docs for auth but cant figure out, here is what I have done till now.

**Protected the routes**

```
Route::api(['version' => 'v1', 'protected' => true], function () {

    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
});
```

**Added JWT auth provider in `dingo/config`**

```
'jwt' => function ($app) {
    return new Dingo\Api\Auth\JWTProvider($app['tymon.jwt.auth']);
 }
```

**Installed the JWT-Auth from [Github docs](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)**

**Tried Login using below sample code from JWT-Auth docs** using Postman but getting `{token : false}`

```
 Route::post('auth/login', function () {
        $credentials = Input::only('email', 'password');

        if ( ! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials) )
        {
            // return 401 error response
        }

        return Response::json(compact('token'));
});
```

If someone can guide how I can `login` `logout`, & `signup` user and make a request with `Authorization: Bearer <token>` will be very helpful.

**If someone could share your `auth` controller for same will be lifesaver :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not returning a response when the credentials are incorrect - so the token will be equal to false in that case.

Here is an example:

```php
Route::post('auth/login', function () {
    $credentials = Input::only('email', 'password');

    if ( ! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials) )
    {
        // return the 401 response
        return Response::json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
    }

    return Response::json(compact('token'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks @tymondesigns. Its working now, problem was in User model of laravel.